# "Закордонний" - "закордоння"?

Tags: синоніми, словотворення

Поширеним є як прикметник "зарубіжний", так і іменник "зарубіжжя".

Також часто використовується прикметник "закордонний". Наприклад, у словосполученні "закордонний паспорт".

*Та чи можна за аналогією утворити слово "закордоння"?*

Таке слово міститься [тут](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=21&t=100757):

> Закордоння
>   іменник середнього роду

Однак, більше енциклопедичних згадок я не знайшла, що, безумовно, наштовхує на сумніви щодо правильності вживання цього слова.

*Чи правильно буде вживати слово "закордоння"?*

Comment: Схоже: [**Закордон** чи **за кордон**, **закордоном** чи **за кордоном**?](/questions/900/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Слово «закордоння» існує, але є розмовним](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=134285&page=982).

До речі, [слово «закордон» (як іменник) теж є розмовним](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=29855&page=982).

А от [слово «зарубіжжя» вже нейтральне](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=135316&page=1039).

Джерело: «Словник української мови» в 20 томах.